# Versioning components in ReactJs

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, versioning

I'm building a components library for a ReactJs application, using bootstrap + sass. My question is, thinking in the future and before start building the app itself: is there any good approach to versioning components?

Let's say that I created a Jumbotron component, reusable of course, but later I want to create a new version with new "superpowers" and gradually replace the old ones, without having to make a big change all at once. What would be a good approach?:

- A version for each component in the same library? (something like: `<Jumbotron v="2" />` or `<Jumbotron2 />`)
- A new library to @import newer versions?
- No need to versioning at all?

This idea came from a post written by a Wallmart developer in "medium":

https://medium.com/walmartlabs/how-to-achieve-reusability-with-react-components-81edeb7fb0e0

At some point it says:

> Components are then published in our private npm registry, meaning that developers can easily install a specific component version, ensuring that their apps won’t suddenly break on upgrade.

This caught my attention because I'm building the UI for a future social network like application, and I'm trying to bootstrap it as organized as I can. And suddenly I realized that it might be a good idea to start coding with this already solved in my mind.

Comment: What i do is i transform the old one to a 'deprecation warning' and make the body a convert to the new one to have the same output. So if you add a field to make it vertical or horizontal and normally it was only horizontal, it would auto-fill it to be horizontal.

Comment: thanks @joviDeCroock ! sounds like a good approach for the case that I described above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of that article, and specifically that paragraph you've highlighted, is around sharing re-usable components across multiple projects, teams and apps. Allowing each team to upgrade the npm version in their own time.

Correct me if I'm wrong, but it sounds like you're working on a singular app, from which you can only have one npm version of a UI library at a time.

If you want multiple versions of a component in the same app there's nothing stopping you naming it `<Jumbotron2 />`. But be warned, this will quickly add complexity to your code and bloat your package.

Another option would be to ensure you keep backwards compatibility when you add your 'superpowers', but it all depends on what these are.

Comment: Thanks Christopher! this is the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You could use semantic versioning for your component and package.json in your app to upgrade your component.
In this case - for minor changes (meaning that API of your component is preserved) and bugfixes you should use the last two numbers of semver. But for major changes - use the first number.

https://semver.org/
https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/semantic-versioning

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply!